# Purging empty dictionaries from list of dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries like so:

```
[{'a':'21'},{},{'b':20'},{'c':'89'},{}]
```

What's the most efficient way to purge empty dictionaries from this list, end result being:

```
[{'a':'21'},{'b':'20'},{'c':'89'}]
```

---

I'm trying:

```
new_list_of_dictionaries = []
for dictionary in list_of_dictionaries:
    if dictionary:
        new_list_of_dictionaries.append(dictionary)
return new_list_of_dictionaries
```

I don't suppose this can be done in O(1) or something?

Comment: How did you end up with the empty dictionaries there in the first place? Probably you can create the list without them

Comment: I think I've seen this exact question for strings, lists, dictionaries, and tuples now - understandably since people don't google the same problem for a different structure.. I wonder what will be next :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters♦: Correct me if I'm wrong but `filter` is the same as using a list comprehension in terms of time complexity. It just reads differently. Yes?

Comment: @HassanBaig: yes, a filter tests each object, so is O(N) too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a list comprehension, and filter on the boolean truth. An empty dictionary is considered *false*:

```
return [d for d in list_of_dictionaries if d]
```

In Python 2, you could also use the [`filter()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter), using `None` as the filter:

```
return filter(None, list_of_dictionaries)
```

In Python 3 that returns an iterator, not a list, so you'd have to call `list()` on that (so `return list(filter(None, ...))`), at which point the list comprehension is simply more readable. Of course, if you don't actually need to have random access to the result (so direct index access to `result[whatever]`), then an iterator might still be a good idea anyway.

Note that this *has* to take O(N) time, you have to test each and every dictionary. Even if lists had some kind of automaticly updated map that lets you get the indices of the dictionaries that are empty in O(1) time, removing items from a list requires moving later entries forward.

Answer (score 4):

Comprehension or `filter` ([Python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter), [Python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)):

```
return filter(None, list_of_dictionaries)

# Python3, if you prefer a list over an iterator
return list(filter(None, list_of_dictionaries))
```

`None` as filter function will filter out all non-truthy elements, which in the case of empty collections makes it quite concise.

Comment: @MartijnPieters True, added some clarification.

Answer (score 3):

could use a list comprehension?

```
myList = [{'a':'21'},{},{'b':'20'},{'c':'89'},{}]

result = [x for x in myList if x]
```

Answer (score -2):

I did it in this way

```
d = [{'a': '21'}, {}, {'b': 20}, {'c': '89'}, {}]
new_d = []
for item in d:
    check = bool(item)
    if not check:
        del item
    else:
        new_d.append(item)

print(new_d)
```

[{'a': '21'}, {'b': 20}, {'c': '89'}]

Comment: The `del item` is entirely redundant. Building a new list like this is slower than a list comprehension, as you incur the `new_d.append` lookup cost each time, as well as the frame stacking cost for the method call.

Comment: The `bool()` call is entirely redundant, because that is what `if` and `not` do *already*. It is simply busywork, extra cycles you could do without.